# How do I get functions/aliases defined in a bash script that's downloaded from a server (and executed) to work?

Tags: bash, wget

I had a `.bashrc` that I moved to server so that I can download and execute it through `wget`:

```
wget -O - http://xxx.github.io/dotfiles/bashrc | bash
```

It does get executed but any functions and aliases defined in that script don't work.

Is there any way to get my functions defined as they would be if the script were run locally?

Comment: The problem is that bash is being executed as a child of the shell from which you executed that command. The functions and aliases in the downloaded file are defined in that child process's environment, but not the parent's environment. The only way I know of to get those definitions into your shell's environment is to save the downloaded file, then source it, e.g. `. bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [garyjohn described in his comment](//superuser.com/questions/794504/do-functions-aliases-defined-in-a-bash-script-thats-downloaded-from-a-server-an#comment1036760_794504),
the problem with

```
wget  (options and args)  |  bash
```

is that,
at least is some shells (bash apparently being one of them),
a pipeline (`cmd1 | cmd2`)
forces all component commands into separate processes. 
When you run `something | bash`,
the newly spawned bash shell process is a separate process
from your main, parent, interactive shell. 
Any functions, aliases, etc.,
that are defined in the output of the command on the left
will be defined in the new bash shell —
which will then exit without reading any commands
from your terminal/keyboard,
thus dumping you back in your original shell,
without the functions, etc.

As garyjohn suggested, one way to solve this problem
and get the functions, aliases, etc., defined in your main shell
is to download the commands into a file, then source it;
e.g.,

```
wget -O - http://xxx.github.io/dotfiles/bashrc > bashrc  &&  . bashrc  &&  rm bashrc
```

But that’s not the only way. 
The trick is to create a pipe without creating a pipeline. 
The trick to doing this is using *process substitution*
(a bash extension to *command substitution*).

```
.  <(wget -O - http://xxx.github.io/dotfiles/bashrc)
```

will define the functions, aliases, etc., without creating a temporary file.

---

Another approach is

```
wget -O - http://xxx.github.io/dotfiles/bashrc  |  . /dev/stdin
```

This won’t work for bash
(because it does the **`.`** command in a subshell),
but it might work for some other shells (e.g., ksh).

---

Of course, the standard warning applies:
be cautious about executing commands you download from the web. 
If you’re using a hardened server on a local network,
the above may be somewhat safe. 
Otherwise, if somebody hacks the web server,
you’re opening the door for him to run arbitrary commands on your machine. 
It would be safer (although clearly more tedious)
to download the commands into a file and then checksum it. 
Then, if the checksum is correct, you can source the file.

Comment: Related: [using ```source``` command with dialog](//superuser.com/q/1182968/354511).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
wget -qO - https://raw.github.com/cescoferraro/dotfiles/master/src/os/setup.sh | xargs bash -c
```